# How to add a datacolumn with a expression which should have a ternary operator

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code which should add a datacolumn to an existing datatable.

Basically  the logic is, if the field Filename is equal to DispForm, then it should print #, but if its not, then print Path on that datacolumn.

However I get this error:

> Syntax error: Missing operand before '=' operator.

```
var fileNameUrl = new DataColumn("FileNameUrl")
{
    Expression = String.Format("[{0}] == 'DispForm.aspx' ? '#' : [{1}]", "FileName", "Path")
};
resultingDataTable.Columns.Add(fileNameUrl);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `IFF` function which has the signature `IIf(expr, truepart, falsepart)`

```
var fileNameUrl = new DataColumn("FileNameUrl")
{
    Expression = "IIF( [FileName] = 'DispForm.aspx' , '#' , [Path])"
};
```